# How to perform Flawless "Gun Show" move on Dance Central 2, ""What Is Love"?

Tags: dance-central-2

I can't reach a flawless performance of the *Gun Show* move on "*What Is Love*" (at least not consistently). I looked at several videos of others performing the song and all perform it "nice" not "flawless". Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion I got from my resident Dance Central expert was that the Kinect has trouble recognizing you when you have parts of your body in front of other body parts.  She suggested starting with your upper arm closer to parallel to the ground, so that the Kinect can pick it up, before you move it across the front of your body.  Keeping your arm further in front of you as you move it across your body will also give the Kinect a somewhat better chance of catching it.

She also suggested making more exaggerated motions.  "When doing that move, I always felt like a cheerleader - super exuberant."